# Dynamically create parameter from array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this [plugin](https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/) on my website, which works great. You can pass a parameter for state specific styles, it looks like this:

```
$('#map').usmap({

    showLabels: false,
    stateStyles: {
        fill : '#ffffff',
        stroke : '#4f4f4f',
        'stroke-width' : 4,
    },

    stateHoverStyles: {
        fill : '#ffffff'
    },

    stateSpecificStyles: {
        'IN': {
            fill : '#84b8e7'
        },

        'CA': {
            fill : '#84b8e7'    
        },

        'TX': {
            fill : '#84b8e7'    
        }
    },

    stateSpecificHoverStyles: {

        'IN': {
            fill : '#0972ce'    
        },

        'CA': {
            fill : '#0972ce'    
        },

        TX': {
            fill : '#0972ce'    
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to fill in those state styles dynamically from an array that looks like ["CA", "IN", "TX"]. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible! If you share your relevant code/efforts the community is much more likely to assist you =)  (please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Will do, thanks. I made some efforts on my own but figured they'd pretty much just be nonsense. I'll post them next time, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for a way to create an object that looks like that, this snippet will do it for you. Let us know more about what you have/need, and I can expand this.

```js
var arr = ['CA', 'IN', 'TX'], // Your state vars
    output = [];

arr.forEach(function(el) {
  output[el] = {
    fill: '#000000' // Could come from the same array, if needed
  };
)};
            
console.log(output);
```

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you have any other questions.